# Rocketchat - localhost:3000 is not working even after resolving most of its issue

Tags: mongodb, npm, rocket.chat

I have done so far:

1. curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
2. git clone https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.git
3. cd Rocket.Chat
4. meteor npm start
   Reference: [https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/quick-start/][1]
   [https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/11099][1]

Output after running - meteor npm start

> > Rocket.Chat@0.69.0-develop start /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat
> >     meteor npm i && meteor
> >
> > Rocket.Chat@0.69.0-develop postinstall /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat
> >     cd packages/rocketchat-katex && npm i
>
> up to date in 0.058s npm WARN chai-as-promised@6.0.0 requires a peer
>   of chai@>= 2.1.2 < 4 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   abbrev@1.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev): npm WARN
>   enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ansi-regex@2.1.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ansi-regex.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: aproba@1.2.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/aproba): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/aproba'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.aproba.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: balanced-match@1.0.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/balanced-match): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/balanced-match'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.balanced-match.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chownr@1.0.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/chownr): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/chownr'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.chownr.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: code-point-at@1.1.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/code-point-at): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/code-point-at'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.code-point-at.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: concat-map@0.0.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/concat-map): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/concat-map'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.concat-map.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   console-control-strings@1.1.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/console-control-strings): npm WARN
>   enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/console-control-strings'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.console-control-strings.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: core-util-is@1.0.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/core-util-is): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/core-util-is'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.core-util-is.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: deep-extend@0.5.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/deep-extend): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/deep-extend'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.deep-extend.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: delegates@1.0.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/delegates): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/delegates'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.delegates.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: detect-libc@1.0.3
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/detect-libc): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/detect-libc'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.detect-libc.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fs.realpath@1.0.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/fs.realpath): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/fs.realpath'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.fs.realpath.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: has-unicode@2.0.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/has-unicode): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/has-unicode'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.has-unicode.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: inherits@2.0.3
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/inherits): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/inherits'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.inherits.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ini@1.3.5
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ini.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: isarray@1.0.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/isarray): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/isarray'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.isarray.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@0.0.8
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.minimist.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ms@2.0.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ms): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ms'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ms.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: debug@2.6.9
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/debug): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/debug'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.debug.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-bundled@1.0.3
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-bundled): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-bundled'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.npm-bundled.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-packlist@1.1.10
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-packlist): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-packlist'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.npm-packlist.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: number-is-nan@1.0.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/number-is-nan): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/number-is-nan'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.number-is-nan.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: object-assign@4.1.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/object-assign): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/object-assign'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.object-assign.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-homedir@1.0.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-homedir): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-homedir'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.os-homedir.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-tmpdir@1.0.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-tmpdir): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-tmpdir'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.os-tmpdir.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: osenv@0.1.5
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/osenv): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/osenv'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.osenv.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: nopt@4.0.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/nopt): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/nopt'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.nopt.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: path-is-absolute@1.0.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/path-is-absolute): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/path-is-absolute'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.path-is-absolute.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   process-nextick-args@2.0.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/process-nextick-args): npm WARN
>   enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/process-nextick-args'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.process-nextick-args.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist): npm
>   WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/.minimist.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safe-buffer@5.1.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safe-buffer): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safe-buffer'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.safe-buffer.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safer-buffer@2.1.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safer-buffer): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safer-buffer'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.safer-buffer.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iconv-lite@0.4.21
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/iconv-lite): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/iconv-lite'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.iconv-lite.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sax@1.2.4
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/sax): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/sax'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.sax.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: needle@2.2.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/needle): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/needle'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.needle.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: semver@5.5.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/semver): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/semver'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.semver.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: set-blocking@2.0.0
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/set-blocking): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/set-blocking'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.set-blocking.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: signal-exit@3.0.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/signal-exit): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/signal-exit'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.signal-exit.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   strip-json-comments@2.0.1
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/strip-json-comments): npm WARN
>   enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/strip-json-comments'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.strip-json-comments.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: rc@1.2.7
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/.staging/rc-73cc394e'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: util-deprecate@1.0.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/util-deprecate): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/util-deprecate'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.util-deprecate.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: are-we-there-yet@1.1.4
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/are-we-there-yet): npm WARN enoent
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/are-we-there-yet'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.are-we-there-yet.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wrappy@1.0.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/wrappy): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/wrappy'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.wrappy.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: rimraf@2.6.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.rimraf.DELETE'
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.0.2
>   (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/yallist): npm WARN enoent SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/yallist'
>   -> '/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.yallist.DELETE'
>
> up to date in 8.923s [[[[[ ~/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat ]]]]]
>
> => Started proxy.                              up to date in 3.594sd package rocketchat...  /
>   => Meteor 1.7.0.5 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
>   => Started MongoDB.                            I20180831-17:41:29.989(5.5)? Updating process.env.MAIL_URL
>   I20180831-17:41:30.486(5.5)? Starting Email Intercepter...
>   I20180831-17:41:32.239(5.5)? LocalStore: store created at 
>   I20180831-17:41:32.240(5.5)? LocalStore: store created at 
>   I20180831-17:41:32.240(5.5)? LocalStore: store created at 
>   I20180831-17:41:32.576(5.5)? Setting default file store to GridFS
>   I20180831-17:41:36.519(5.5)? Exception in callback of async function:
>   TypeError: connect.bodyParser is not a function
>   I20180831-17:41:36.519(5.5)?     at saml_server.js
>   (/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/steffo_meteor-accounts-saml.js:450:36)
>   I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?     at fileEvaluate
>   (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9) I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?
>   at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
>   I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?     at
>   /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/steffo_meteor-accounts-saml.js:1234:1
>   I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?     at
>   /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/steffo_meteor-accounts-saml.js:1241:3
>   I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?     at
>   /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
>   I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?     at Array.forEach
>   (:null:null) I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?     at
>   /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
>   I20180831-17:41:36.520(5.5)?     at
>   /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
>   I20180831-17:41:36.521(5.5)?     at Function.run
>   (/home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
>   I20180831-17:41:36.521(5.5)?     at
>   /home/synoriq/Documents/synoriq/Rocket.Chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
>   I20180831-17:41:36.521(5.5)?